# sql- Number of actual records added

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to generate a report based on counselling and actual to see how many counseling were converted to actual.

I have table which has Patient, Booking Category, Doctor, Booking.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88c2b/1)**

[image]

Following are the business rules

1. Fetch all the bookings made by patients if they made booking after counseling
2. The user can take counseling booking first and book one or more bookings that falls under the same counselling group. Example: They can do a first booking `Counseling Dental` then can book anything mapped to that group. i. e Dentail surgery and Teeth repair. These information maintained in `CounselingXActualBookingCategoryMap` table
3. If patient book more than one actual booking consider only one, which is not cancelled
4. If counselling is cancelled dont consider.
5. If actual is cancelled dont consider.
6. Get a total number of counseling bookings(it need not to be a actual booking doctor) and actual bookings for each doctor. Any one can be a counseling doctor. But report we consider only the doctor who did actual

Here is the SQL i tried. But its taking all records instead of one actual for that group.

```
SELECT  P.Name As Patient, SurgeryB.BookingId, SurgeryB.BookingDate, C.CategoryName, 
d.name as doctor
FROM BOOKING CounsB
INNER JOIN BOOKING SurgeryB 
  ON CounsB.PatientId = SurgeryB.PatientId AND ISNULL(SurgeryB.IsCancelled,0)=0
INNER JOIN CounselingXActualBookingCategoryMap MAP 
  ON MAP.CounselingCategoryId = CounsB.CategoryId 
     AND MAP.ActualBookingCategoryId = SurgeryB.CategoryId  
     AND SurgeryB.BookingDate > CounsB.BookingDate
 INNER JOIN PATIENT P ON P.PATIENTID = SurgeryB.PATIENTID
 inner join category c on c.categoryid= SurgeryB.CategoryId
 inner join doctor d on SurgeryB.doctorid = d.doctorid
 WHERE ISNULL(CounsB.IsCancelled,0)=0
 order by p.patientid
```

**Issue:**

1. I do not want to see a record that Alex made booking for Teeth repair, since he already did actual for same group Dental and category `Dental Surgery`

**I want to get counseling and actual made bookings. Example 100 counseling made and only 70 actual booked like that for each counseling category.**

Comment: For the given data what is the expected output?

Comment: @mxix i have updated question. please read last point made in bold text

Answer (score 1):

I have added to your code as below:

```
SELECT  P.Name As Patient, SurgeryB.BookingId, SurgeryB.BookingDate, C.CategoryName, map.GroupId, map.CounselingCategoryId, map.ActualBookingCategoryId,
d.name as doctor
into #temp
FROM BOOKING CounsB
INNER JOIN BOOKING SurgeryB 
  ON CounsB.PatientId = SurgeryB.PatientId AND ISNULL(SurgeryB.IsCancelled,0)=0
INNER JOIN CounselingXActualBookingCategoryMap MAP 
  ON MAP.CounselingCategoryId = CounsB.CategoryId 
     AND MAP.ActualBookingCategoryId = SurgeryB.CategoryId  
     AND SurgeryB.BookingDate > CounsB.BookingDate
 INNER JOIN PATIENT P ON P.PATIENTID = SurgeryB.PATIENTID
 inner join category c on c.categoryid= SurgeryB.CategoryId
 inner join doctor d on SurgeryB.doctorid = d.doctorid
 WHERE ISNULL(CounsB.IsCancelled,0)=0
 order by p.patientid

;with cte as 
(   
    select Patient, BookingId, BookingDate, CategoryName, Doctor, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Patient, GroupId order by BookingDate) row_num 
    from #temp t
)
select Patient, BookingId, BookingDate, CategoryName, Doctor from cte where row_num = 1

drop table #temp
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer to the query you gave as an example, which is described in business rule 1 and to the one in business rule 6.

I made some slight changes to your tables, since I had to re-create them to test the query anyway.

```
create table patient
(
  id                     int,
  name                   varchar(8)
);

create table doctor
(
  id                     int,
  name                   varchar(8)
);

create table category
(
  id                     int,
  name                   varchar(20),
  counseling_or_surgery  varchar(10)
);

create table map
(
  counseling_category_id   int,
  surgery_category_id      int,
  group_id                 int
);

create table booking
(
  id                       int,
  patient_id               int,
  category_id              int,
  doctor_id                int,
  booking_date             date,
  cancelled                bit
);
```

Here are the inserts to set up the data:

```
insert into patient (id, name) values (1, 'Alex');
insert into patient (id, name) values (2, 'John');
insert into patient (id, name) values (3, 'Mark');
insert into patient (id, name) values (4, 'Stephen');

insert into doctor (id, name) values (1, 'Doctor 1');
insert into doctor (id, name) values (2, 'Doctor 2');
insert into doctor (id, name) values (3, 'Doctor 3');

insert into category (id, name, counseling_or_surgery) values (1, 'Counseling Dental', 'Counseling');
insert into category (id, name, counseling_or_surgery) values (2, 'Counseling Nose',   'Counseling');
insert into category (id, name, counseling_or_surgery) values (3, 'Dental surgery',    'Surgery');
insert into category (id, name, counseling_or_surgery) values (4, 'Teeth repair',      'Surgery');
insert into category (id, name, counseling_or_surgery) values (5, 'Nose Surgery',      'Surgery');
insert into category (id, name, counseling_or_surgery) values (6, 'Nose adjustment',   'Surgery');

insert into map (counseling_category_id, surgery_category_id, group_id) values (1, 3, 1);
insert into map (counseling_category_id, surgery_category_id, group_id) values (1, 4, 1);
insert into map (counseling_category_id, surgery_category_id, group_id) values (2, 5, 2);
insert into map (counseling_category_id, surgery_category_id, group_id) values (2, 6, 2);

insert into booking (id, patient_id, category_id, doctor_id, booking_date, cancelled) values ( 1, 1, 1, 1, '2017-11-20', 'false');
insert into booking (id, patient_id, category_id, doctor_id, booking_date, cancelled) values ( 2, 1, 3, 3, '2017-11-25', 'false');
insert into booking (id, patient_id, category_id, doctor_id, booking_date, cancelled) values ( 3, 1, 4, 2, '2017-11-25', 'false');
insert into booking (id, patient_id, category_id, doctor_id, booking_date, cancelled) values ( 4, 1, 2, 1, '2017-11-21', 'true');
insert into booking (id, patient_id, category_id, doctor_id, booking_date, cancelled) values ( 5, 1, 2, 2, '2017-11-26', 'false');
insert into booking (id, patient_id, category_id, doctor_id, booking_date, cancelled) values ( 6, 1, 5, 3, '2017-11-28', 'false');
insert into booking (id, patient_id, category_id, doctor_id, booking_date, cancelled) values ( 7, 3, 2, 2, '2017-11-26', 'false');
insert into booking (id, patient_id, category_id, doctor_id, booking_date, cancelled) values ( 8, 3, 6, 2, '2017-11-26', 'true');
insert into booking (id, patient_id, category_id, doctor_id, booking_date, cancelled) values ( 9, 4, 2, 2, '2017-11-29', 'false');
insert into booking (id, patient_id, category_id, doctor_id, booking_date, cancelled) values (10, 4, 5, 1, '2017-11-29', 'false');
```

Given these tables, here is the query for business rule 1:

```
select
    c.name          as patient,
    b.id            as booking_id,
    b.booking_date  as first_surgery_date,
    d.name          as first_surgery,
    e.name          as doctor
from
    (
        select
            r.patient_id,
            min(r.id)           as booking_id,
            t.group_id
        from
            booking r
            join
            category s
            on r.category_id = s.id
            join
            map t
            on t.surgery_category_id = r.category_id
        where
            r.cancelled = 0 and
            s.counseling_or_surgery = 'Surgery'
        group by
            r.patient_id,
            t.group_id
    ) a
    join
    booking b
    on a.booking_id = b.id
    join
    patient c
    on b.patient_id = c.id
    join 
    category d
    on b.category_id = d.id
    join
    doctor e
    on b.doctor_id = e.id;
```

and the results are:

```
patient          booking_id  first_surgery_date first_surgery    doctor
---------------- ----------- ------------------ ---------------- ----------------
Stephen                   10         2017-11-29 Nose Surgery     Doctor 1
Alex                       2         2017-11-25 Dental surgery   Doctor 3
Alex                       6         2017-11-28 Nose Surgery     Doctor 3

(3 rows affected)
```

Here's the query for business rule 6.  It counts cancellations too; easy to change if that's not what you want.

```
select
    z.name                     as doctor,
    y.total_counseling_bookings,
    x.total_surgery_bookings
from
    (
        select
            doctor_id,
            count(*) as total_surgery_bookings
        from
            booking a
            join
            category b
            on a.category_id = b.id
        where
            b.counseling_or_surgery = 'Surgery'
        group by 
            doctor_id
    ) x
    full outer join
    (
        select
            doctor_id,
            count(*) as total_counseling_bookings
        from
            booking c
            join
            category d
            on c.category_id = d.id
        where
            d.counseling_or_surgery = 'Counseling'
        group by 
            doctor_id
    ) y
    on x.doctor_id = y.doctor_id
    join
    doctor z
    on x.doctor_id = z.id
```

and here are the results for this one:

```
doctor   total_counseling_bookings total_surgery_bookings
-------- ------------------------- ----------------------
Doctor 1                         2                      1
Doctor 2                         3                      2
Doctor 3                      NULL                      2

(3 rows affected)
```